# Is there a solution to install DRAKE on my WLS Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: shell, windows-10, workflow, ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to install "Drake" (text-based data workflow tool) in a (WSL) Windows Subsystem for Linux and I try the steps in the book Data Science At The Command Line's Chapter 06 and the Drake's [github repository](https://github.com/Factual/drake) I've followed all the steps without any problem, but when I try to install "Drip" [github repository](https://github.com/flatland/drip) with this code

```
$ git clone https://github.com/flatland/drip.git
$ cd drip
$ make prefix=~/bin install
```

I had this :
[image]
I desperately tried a few things like adjusting the java's environment variables for my windows system and in my WSL Ubuntu too, without success

My Windows Build is :
[image]
And my WSL is:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was to install "DRAKE" a Data workflow tool, after being searching for a solution I heard about [Homebrew](https://docs.brew.sh/Formula-Cookbook#homebrew-terminology) a solution made initially for installing tools on macOS and it's available now for linux even for WSL!

like in magic just type the tool to install and it's automatically done even if it's requires dependencies

```
brew install drake
```

So for nubies like me it's a welcome tool which can save you a lot of time.